# Best approach to filter the couchbase documents based on user inputs

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, couchbase

We have more than 200000 records of employee in coucbase.

Based on user input, lets say get all employee, whose department is CSE and salary is greater than 10k.

Like this user can give any filter criteria only for certain attributes of employee object.

We have spring boot application and rest end point exposed to perform this processing.

We use java sdk to write queries to couchbase.

To solve this, i have used the java 8 streams and filter as below:

```
empList.stream().filter(
        null== nameFilter ? e -> true : e -> nameFilter.equals(e.getName())).
        filter(
                null== idFilter ? e -> true : e -> idFilter.equals(e.getId())).
        filter(
                null== statusFilter ? e -> true : e ->statusFilter.equals(e.getStatus())).
        filter(
                null== isActive ? e -> true : e ->isActive.equals(e.isActive())).
        collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Is this correct approach to filter?

Is there any approach, which performs better than this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you want to take the various user filters and produce a single N1QL statement from them.  This should be much more efficient than fetching all documents and filtering in the application (which from the code sample it looks like you're doing).

Comment: Have you considered running a native couchbase n1ql query using the couchbase java client?